# COALESCE with condition check as first column

Tags: sql-server

I need help to resolve error as <> symbol for SQL SERVER COALESCE with condition check as first column.

For Example, I need to successfully run below code without any error in SQL SERVER

```
select *,
COALESCE(x.START_DATE <> x.prv_plus1, 0)
from (SELECT EMP_ID, [START_DATE], [END_DATE],
DATEADD(DAY, 1,LAG([END_DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY START_DATE)) as prv_plus1
FROM dbo.EMP_ABSENCE_DTLS
) x;
```

Comment: Error I am getting is "Incorrect syntax near '<'." for above query due to line no 2  compare i.e. <>

Comment: SQL Server does not handle Boolean expressions as such,   perhaps a simple case when x.START_DATE <> x.prv_plus1 then 1 else 0 end

Answer (score 0):

Here the query should be

`select *, COALESCE(CASE WHEN x.START_DATE <> x.prv_plus1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, 0) from (SELECT EMP_ID, [START_DATE], [END_DATE], DATEADD(DAY, 1,LAG([END_DATE]) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY START_DATE)) as prv_plus1 FROM dbo.EMP_ABSENCE_DTLS ) x;`